# calculo de registros coincidentes por año (if dentro de un foreach)

Tags: php

Estoy buscando solucion a un error que me salta, supongo que será por un mal planteamiento. Quiero hacer un recuento de registros que coinciden en un año, por lo que tengo un controlador que saca el listado de todos los registros y en el codigo para indicarme el numero que coinciden con el año actual pongo lo siguiente:

```
<?php
   $fechahoraentera = strtotime($fechahora);
   $anio = date("Y", $fechahoraentera);
   $contador_de_formaciones = 0;

   foreach ($formaciones_datos as $formaciones_dato) {
     if (date("Y", $formaciones_dato['fecha_fr']) == $anio) {
        $contador_de_formaciones = $contador_de_formaciones + 1;
     }
   }
?>
<h2><?php echo $contador_de_formaciones; ?><sup style="font-size: 20px"></h2>
<p>Formaciones año: <?php echo $anio; ?></p>
```

Teniendo en cuenta que tengo una variable fija $fechahora que es de donde saco el año actual.

podéis echarme un cable?

Comment: Y el error que salta es....?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: date(): Argument #2 ($timestamp) must be of type ?int, string given in

Comment: Hace un `var_dump($formaciones_datos);` y muéstrame lo que te coloca

Comment: perdona por mi ignorancia de "novato", como se ejecuta el var_dump

Comment: Así tal cual como lo puse, pega esa línea en lugar del `for`. Eso imprimirá el contenido `$formaciones_datos`, algo así: `array(4) { [0]=> array(1) { ["fecha_fr"]=> int` y eso que te imprima, me lo muestras

Comment: array(13) { [0]=> array(25) { ["id_formacion"]=> string(2) "20" ["nroformacion"]=> string(1) "4" ["tipo_fr"]=> string(1) "1" ["fecha_fr"]=> string(10) "2024-01-25" ["fechacad_fr"]=> string(10) "2024-01-25" ["formador_fr"]=> string(1) "1" ["id_tipoformacion"]=> string(1) "1" ["nombre_tf"]=> string(20) "Puesto de trabajo 1h" ["duracion_tf"]=> string(1) "1" ["validez_tf"]=> string(1) "3" ["detalles_tf"]=> string(1109) "For

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pasa que en el Array asociativo que tienes, la clave `fecha_fr` guarda un elemento del tipo `string` y la función `date` requiere un `timestamp` que es una fecha en formato `int`. Lo que tienes que hacer es usar `strtotime` (tal como lo haces en tu primera linea de código) para convertir un `string` en `timestamp`

```
 if (date("Y", strtotime($formaciones_dato['fecha_fr'])) == $anio) {
```

---

Por último también puedes usar `count` y `array_filter` para contar las ocurrencias

```
$fechahoraentera = strtotime($fechahora);
$anio = date("Y", $fechahoraentera);
$contador_de_formaciones = count( array_filter($formaciones_datos, fn($n) => date("Y", strtotime($n['fecha_fr'])) == $anio) );
```

Comment: muchas gracias, me he decantado por el count y array_filter ya que lo veo mucho mas simple y logico